# VBA, Save button wont work correctly

Tags: vba, excel, button, userform

I want the caption of save button change  into "please wait" when i click it then after the workbook is saved the caption will return to its original caption "SAVE". Heres my code..

```
Private sub cmdSave_Click()
cmdSave.Caption = "Please wait"
ThisWorkbook.SAVE
UserForm1.Show
MsgBox "Saving Successful"
cmdSave.Caption = "SAVE"
End Sub
```

My save button is at userform1, i put userform1.show because when i click save the userform1 hides,

My problem is that the "please wait" caption code runs delay after i press the save button.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Name your button `cmdSave` and put the following in the `UserForm`:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    cmdSave.Caption = "Please wait"
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    MsgBox "Saving Successful!"
    cmdSave.Caption = "SAVE"
End Sub
```

This is how it works:

[image]

Comment: I tried your code but the "please wait" caption is delay..the msgbox and please wait appears together..